# based on a line character, print corresponding number next to it

Tags: text-processing, awk, printf

I have the following input format,

```
H
O
C
H
H
C
H
H
O
C
H
H
C
```

I would like to obtain the following output,

```
H1
O1
C1
H2
H3
C2
H4
H5
O2
C3
H6
H7
C4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `awk` commands as below. The below will simply reconstruct the whole line `{..}1` by appending to the current line `$0` with the value marking the count of occurrence of the word in the file.

```
awk '{ $0 = $0 "" ++unique[$0] }1' file
```

The part `unique[$0]` creates a hash-map with the value of `$0` as the key, i.e. `unique['H'], unique['O']` etc. The pre-increment on it will increment the value at the array as `unique['H']=1`, `unique['H']=2` and so on. We can also just append the counter to the end of each line instead of explicitly re-creating each line

```
awk '{ print($0 "" ++unique[$0]) }' file
```

An equivalent Perl version, with the same logic inplace

```
perl -lpe '{ $_ .= ++$unique{$_} }' file
```

That latter one could easily be adapted to cases where characters are not each on separate lines like:

```
$ echo ABBC | perl -lpe 's/./$& . ++$unique{$&}/ge'
A1B1B2C1
```